# VSCode IntelliSense - how to declare types

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I'm trying to minimally use TypeScript types in my JS projects so that IntelliSence can provide better completions and I get warnings about type-related problems.

I added a `jsconfig.json` file that sets up the typechecking in JS, and I mostly use JSDoc to describe the types. This works pretty well.

Now I'd like to create some types that I use throughout my project. I tried using `types.d.ts` but that seems to be something React-specific and isn't documented.

I also tried putting the types in an `index.d.ts` file, but that only gets read when you're importing from the index and so it won't be useful for the components that implement what is exported from the index.

`/// <reference types="." />` also doesn't import the `index.d.ts` types into the current scope. I resorted to doing `/** @typedef {import('.').Foo} Foo */` for each type I'm using in the current file.

Is there a minimal and maintainable way to manage types in typescript but write the rest in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If the code in js file is:

```js
const a = prompt();
```

the code will be

```js
/** @type {number} */
const a = prompt();
```

Write JSDoc to .js file.

Comment: IntelliSense combine all opened files so if you have 2 opened file, no import needed

Comment: Well, yes, but I was asking about how to define types in Typescript. Jsdoc is not as expressive as Typescript.

Comment: Try classes and objects. No more possibilities!